# Exchange Error 0x80070057 when downloading address book from Outlook 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have a few users receiving the following error when attempting to use Send/Receive to download an offline address book from the Exchange Server (on the intranet):

> Task 'Microsoft Exchange' reported error (0x80070057) : 'Sorry,
>   something went wrong. You may want to try again.'

Other Outlook 2013 users do not have issues downloading the address book. I've found a [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2845987) about it, but it appears to be user-directed rather than admin-directed.

I have found that the users that have issues see "OAB URL: Public Folder" when running the Test E-mail AutoConfiguration tool, which seems to be the cause - they are not receiving the HTTPS link as the OAB URL.

In Exchange, under Client Access > Offline Address Book Distribution, there is only one OAB location set, and that is pointing to our internal and external https paths to distribute the OAB. There is no Public Folder set here.

Why are these users affected by this error receiving "OAB URL: Public Folder"? Presumably this comes from the autodiscover XML sent by the Exchange server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue and I'll post the solution in case anyone is looking here in the future:

We have two mailbox databases that house our mailboxes. The users that were not able to sync their address books were all on the same database. That mailbox database was pointing to an Offline Address Book that was not serving the OAB over HTTPS, it was Public Folder only.

These settings are in EMC, under:

- Organization Configuration > Mailbox > Database Management > (select database) > Properties > Client Settings
- Organization Configuration > Mailbox > Offline Address Book > (select oab) > Properties > Distribution